# Stop the continuous pop-up "problem connecting to the server"

Tags: time-machine

My WDMyCloud died and my Mac (Catalina) is continually looking to connect to it.

I get the following message:
[image: problem connecting to server pop up]

I have tried the usual and there is nothing in the login items.

I have run the console and managed to find the following, which appears with the pop up message.

[image: console error messages]

It references the NetAuthSysAgent.app, but I cannot see how Time machine is still using this disk. I have removed the disk from Time machine, so any recommendations welcome as the pop up is sending me crazy!

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/253781/ how did you remove the disk ? https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128280/how-to-disable-time-machine-for-an-external-hard-drive